# How do I parse command line arguments included in double brackets?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

It is easy to split a line of arguments using:

```
// get arguments for myProg.exe /n /b /c
string.Split(' ');
```

What about the following list:

```
// get arguments for myProg.exe /n /b /c:"MyProg 4.0"
```

Will string split help even in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: The command-line arguments come in a string array called argv right? So no splitting is necessary.

Comment: @Mohamed: It's true, thanks! Please add an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, I originally just did a comment because I didn't know if I got the question right. I posted the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reposting my comment as an answer.*

Since the command-line arguments come as a string array with argv, there is really no need to do any splitting at all:

```
public static void Main (string[] argv)
{
  foreach (string arg in argv) {
    Console.WriteLine("arg: {0}", arg);
  }
}
```

If you call the program like: `myProg.exe /n /b /c:"MyProg 4.0"`, you should see the following:

```
arg: /n
arg: /b
arg: /c:MyProg 4.0
```

The only time splitting will be needed is when you're parsing a specific argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        var arr = arg.Split(':');
        if (arr.Length == 2)
        {
            string name = arr[0];
            string value = arr[1];
            // parse arg as a key-value pair
        }
        else
        {
            // parse arg as a flag
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `/c:"Some:Argument"`, rare as they are. You can add the `arg.Split(':', 2)` to get at max two strings from split.

Comment: @Patrick: True, very rare. In my opinion - application command-line argument convention should not support such notation. It's rather better to use `/xml:File` for such cases.

Comment: Although, specifying a full path will include a : `/file:"C:\Folder"`. What do you mean with /xml:File?

Comment: @Patrick: I mean that if complex configuration is required to be passed via command-line arguments, it's better to support XML-formatted file containing all this settings rather then pass it as "raw" arguments by turn

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using NDesk.Options. It's a getopt-like library for C#.

http://www.ndesk.org/Options

Answer (score -1):

you should split on the argument separator because i can write the parameters without spaces while still correct: myProg.exe /n/b/c:"MyProg 4.0"

```
string.Split('/')
```

Comment: I never saw an application that could parse stuck arguments. Well formed arguments should be delimetered by spaces!